# A word or short phrase instead of "the time taken between xxx and xx is..."

Tags: american-english

In looking for a word or short phrase to replace "the time taken in between milestone A and milestone B".

For example a project plan has 4 milestones:

```
Milestone 1: project initiative
Milestone 2: submit proposal
Milestone 3: deliver a working prototype
Milestone 4: submit a business plan
```

Different projects take different time in these milestones. Project A may take {12,10,5,8} days. Project B may take {20,6,15,4} days.

The days taken might be affected by human (e.g. forget, too busy etc), I am looking for a phrase to embody this.

So when describing the time (days) taken in between the milestones, what is the good and simple way to say, instead of "the days required from project initiative to submit proposal is 12".

Thank you.

Comment: Will _time period_ do ?

Comment: Or perhaps _interval_?

Comment: @Conrado, Conrado and user405662, thank you for your comments. Because the days taken might be affected by human (e.g. forget, too busy etc), I am looking for a phrase to embody this. Interval, is quite natural (and it doesn't sound like affected by human factor), isn't it?

Comment: The total time taken is X.

Comment: @FeliniusRex, thank you for the comment. But it's not really about 'total'. :)

Comment: *The days required from project initiative to submit proposal is 12.* --> The total time required is 12 days.

Comment: Time span may be used too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **time lag**?

> an interval of time between two related phenomena (such as a cause and its effect)

*There's a time lag between when you see a stop sign and when your foot steps on the brake.*

[Merriam-Webster]